# populate select box on previous select and with clone

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, clone

I am trying to add cloning functionality for select boxes. 
I have 3 select box: country, state, city and first user select the country and on id basis state select box is populated with options and same with city dropdown will populate only when state is selected.

Then I have add more option where I have regenerate everything. so I am cloning my div but the problem when I change my country instead of showing new state dropdown its returns to previous drop down:

```
  $('.country').on('change',function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        callAjax(id);
    });
    $('.state').on('change',function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        callAjax(id);
    });

  $('#btClone').on('click', function () {

        $('#country')
            .clone()
            .attr('id', 'country_' + i)
            .attr('name', 'country_' + i)
            .appendTo("#container2");
        $('#state')
            .clone()
            .attr('id', 'state_' + i)
            .attr('name', 'state_' + i)
            .appendTo("#container2");
      i =i+1;
    });
```

My Html looks  like

```
 <div id="container1">
                <select id="country" name="country" class="hidden country">
                </select>
                <select id="state" name="state" class="hidden state">
                </select>
                <select id="city" name="city" class="hidden city">
                </select>
             <span id="selected-profile"></span>
             <div id="addons" class="hidden">

                <input type="button" id="btClone" value="Clone the list" style="float:right;" />
             </div>
         </div>
        <div id="container2" style="display:none;"></div>
```

I want when i click on add new then chose country then change something my ajax call again call but as of now i am unable to do that because i already have options

Comment: Where does "i" in your click-handler come from? There should be an error.

Comment: its global variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what exactly do you mean with "instead of showing new state dropdown its returns to previous drop down". I tried your code in a fiddle and it's cloning as expected.

```js
function initRow($row){
  $row.find('select[name="country"]').on('change', function () {
      var thisRow = $(this).closest('div.row');
      var stateDD = thisRow.find($('select[name="state"]'));
      stateDD.show();

      stateDD.on('change',function(){
        var cityDD = thisRow.find('select[name="city"]');
        cityDD.show();
        cityDD.on('change',function(){

        });
      });
  });
}
$('#container1 .row').each(function(){
 initRow($(this));
});
$('#btClone').click(function(){
 var rowTemplate = $('#container1 > .row').eq(0).clone();
  rowTemplate.find('select[name="state"]').hide();
  rowTemplate.find('select[name="city"]').hide();
 initRow(rowTemplate.appendTo($('#container1')));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container1">
  <div class="row">
    <select name="country" class="hidden country">
      <option value=1>country 1</option> <option value=2>country 2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="state" class="hidden state" style="display:none;">
      <option value=1>state 1</option> <option value=2>state 2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="city" class="hidden city" style="display:none;">
       <option value=1>city 1</option> <option value=2>city 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btClone" value="Clone the list" style="float:right;" />
```

Comment: Yeah its cloning but not the way as I want. I want when I click on add new then country drop down show and when I change country then state drop down show with options and same with state dropdown.

Comment: Ok you didn't code that. To achieve that the second dropdown has to be inserted ON CHANGE of the first one. I updated the example code.

Comment: I want to use same ajaxcall method and I am not sure how can I implement that feature

Comment: Build the logic to append the new dropdowns first. Than add your ajax-function to the change events. Step by step

Comment: This clone function is appending dropdown. If I am right? sorry i am very new to programming so dnt know much abt this

Comment: "clone()" doubles the html-element. "append()" appends it to the referenced html element. "change" is another event than "click". Check out my updated example above

Comment: When I click on add more button then click on country to change it appending new state drop down and with previous state drop down options

Comment: if I change 5 time country then it adding 5 new state drop down

Comment: yeah cause it's programmed like that. You got to learn the basics of jquery-events to come up with a specific question.Everything you need to accomplish your needs is in the example above.

Comment: No problem! Would like to help out when you come up with more questions. In the meantime - would you mind to upvote my answer?

Comment: Buddy can you help me how can I append only one dropdown if there is already dropdown. m stuck

Comment: with $(this).off("change"); able to do this :)

Comment: OK i updated the example once again - fitting your needs i hope.

Comment: but we need to make selector dynamic to put option value right? as of nw everything(id , name) is same for every drop down

Comment: Just add a function call for every dropdown which will return the values for that specific select by passing the type e.g. "city" and the function returns an array of cities.

Comment: Yeah I did the same calling ajaxcall(id,state) but in success method of ajax appending data like
 $(data.success).each(function( index, element  ) {
                            $('#'+selectId).append('<option value="' + element.entity_id + '">' + element.name + '</option>');
                        });
But this id is not unique so when I change country in cloned field then state drop gets already previous option